# Allow Team Member to create App IDs

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, app-id

My company decided to outsource the development of an iOS application. We have added their developers as a Team Member of our iOS Program Developer.

In my point of view, the settings of the App IDs is a critical point, and I would prefer to let them manage it. Am I right?

If yes, is there a solution to let them create/update an App IDs, without giving them a Team Admin role? The point is : We want to let them manage the App IDs, provisioning profile, etc... But we do not want to allow them to distribute any applications on the App Store as a Team Admin could.

Thank you for your anser,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three roles available: Team Agent, Team Admin, and Team Member.  Only the Team Agent has the ability to submit apps. Designating a person to be a Team Admin is common to handle the tasks you described.